# How to paginate commits on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Which would be a good solution to paginate commits when I have a query like

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO
    table1
FROM
    table2

INSERT INTO
    table3
FROM
    table4
COMMIT
```

I am dealing with large amounts of data and I am having some problems to commit the whole thing at once, so I would like to commit something like 5000 rows each commit.

Thought about something like

- maxNumber = get the max number of rows among number of rows from table2 and 3
- maxNumber/5000 = numberOfCommits
- create a loop from 1 to numberOfCommits and process data at row number (using ROW_NUMBER()) (n-1)*5000 to n*5000

Would be great to learn how to do it in a better way!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a relationship between `table2` and `table4`? Is the system going to be in use while you're doing the move?

Comment: Yes, table 2 and 4 are related, actually the real scenario is composed of 12 tables that I need to insert data and are linked together (11 of them hold extra information about the other one) and that Is why I need to protect data integrity with the transaction.

Comment: Will there be activity in the database while you're doing this? Do you need to make sure that any new data changes get reflected over? Are you switching over to the new tables with your application? I don't necessarily have a better answer in mind than Remus, but these are questions that you need to think about as they will have a big impact on what your solution should end up looking like.

Comment: Yea, doing some tests here now. Dont think there will be any activity while running it, It is kind of a job that will run once a day when (hopefully) no one is using the database or the application. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Processing an entire table with batches based on ROW_NUMBER() is actually a potentially bad idea. In order to return ROW_NUMBER 5001 the engine has to count 5000 rows first. To read row 10001 it has to count again the first 5000, then the next 5000. And so on and so forth, the pattern is very read intensive. If the tables are small, it matter not, but if they're not...

If your table(s) have at least one unique index (preferably the clustered one) then you can use a combination of `TOP 5000` and `WHERE uniquecolumn > @lastbatchmaxvalue`. If you don't have such an unique index then you can only do this via a cursor.

But maybe the best solution is to get out of the T-SQL constraints. [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) is ideally suited to do exacty this kind of job, it supports batches and works with efficient bulk insert interface when possible.

Comment: Table IDs are UNIQUEIDENTIFIER columns so that @lastbatchmaxvalue would not help I guess. I will give a look at SSIS but think It wont be available to work with, unfortunately.

Comment: Why would an uniquidentifier not work with @lastbatchmaxvalue? Guids sort just fine.

Comment: Thought it would not, my mistake. Will try that. Thanks Remus.